# Call function inside a function

Tags: javascript

Could everyone tell me how to call a function inside a function?
For example :

```
 function betterExampleNeeded() {  
       var a = 1;  
      function oneMoreThanA() {  
        return a + 1;  
      }  
      return oneMoreThanA();  
    }
```

How to call oneMoreThanA( )
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just invoke the function `betterExampleNeeded`

Comment: What's wrong with the way you call `oneMoreThanA()` in your sample?

Comment: I try to call oneMoreThanA() directly in Javascript Console in Chrome. It returns an error  Uncaught ReferenceError: oneMoreThanA is not defined

Comment: oneMoreThanA is a privatemethod so it can not be called from outside. But betterExampleNeeded() function is visible from outside and returns a reference to your method. So you just need to invoke betterExampleNeeded() to run oneMoreThanA() method.

Comment: Thanks for response.   Can I invoke oneMoreThanA() by using betterExampleNeeded() .oneMoreThanA()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `oneMoreThanA` in your example.

If you want to call it from *outside* your `betterExampleNeeded` function, then you'll need to have `betterExampleNeeded` make the functino reference available outside of it, by:

- Returning it
- Assigning it to a variable in the containing scope
- Assigning it to an object property on an argument passed into it

...or similar.

For instance:

```
function betterExampleNeeded() {  
     var a = 1;  
     function oneMoreThanA() {  
        return a + 1;  
     }  
     return oneMoreThanA;     // <=== Note! No ()
 } 

 var f = betterExampleNeeded();
 console.log(f()); // 2
 console.log(f()); // 2
 console.log(f()); // 2
```

Or we could even modify `a`:

```
function betterExampleNeeded() {  
     var a = 1;  
     function oneMoreThanA() {  
        return ++a;           // <=== Modify `a`
     }  
     return oneMoreThanA;
 } 

 var f = betterExampleNeeded();
 console.log(f()); // 2
 console.log(f()); // 3
 console.log(f()); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  I got some problems in understanding javascript. Please correct me , if I am wrong.    A function is a object, if I assign this function to variable. For example, var a =   function betterExampleNeeded() {  
       var a = 1;  
      function oneMoreThanA() {  
        return a + 1;  
      }  
      return oneMoreThanA();  
    }                          can I  call the function inside by using a.oneMoreThanA() ?     Apologies for my format, I dont know how to adjust here.

Comment: sorry, I should have removed "betterExampleNeeded" to make it a anonymous function

Comment: @XuzhengWang: No, because although functions are objects, you haven't set a property on that function with the name `oneMoreThanA`. The `oneMoreThanA` *inside* that function is completely private to code *within* the function, unless (again) you do one of the things listed above to expose it to the outside world.

Comment: @XuzhengWang: Or to put it another way: A function declared inside another function is very much like a local variable. So just like local variables don't become properties of the function instance, functions declared inside them don't either.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I got confused about the difference between var a = function ( ){}   and var a = { }.